# Type signature lacks an accompanying binding?

Tags: haskell

First off, I realize there are a couple other similar questions already asked and answered on here. I looked at them and didn't get anything, so I'm asking again.

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
titlesOfMoviesSatisfying :: (Movie -> Bool) -> [Movie] -> [Title]
titlesOfSatisying f movieDB = map check (zip movieDB (map f movieDB))
```

Movie and Title are both data types I just defined earlier in the code. When I just execute >>let b = map check (zip movieDB (map f movieDB)), I get :type b as [Title], which is exactly what I want. And I have :type movieDB as [Movie] and :type f as Movie -> Bool. So everything seems to be as it should be. But when I try to compile the code above, I get the following:

Example7.hs:65:1:
    The type signature for `titlesOfMoviesSatisfying'
      lacks an accompanying binding
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

You have spelt the name of your function incorrectly:

```
titlesOfMoviesSatisfying :: (Movie -> Bool) -> [Movie] -> [Title] 
titlesOfMoviesSatisfying f movieDB = map check (zip movieDB (map f movieDB))
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo , the code is typed correctly though.

Comment: @Alex: That is what causes that error though, so there must be a typo in the code as well.